# Complete statistic for discrete distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation, complete-statistics

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with the probability mass function
$$P(X=-1)=\theta,\ P(X=0)=1-2\theta,\ P(X=1)=\theta$$
I'm trying to find a complete statistic for $\theta$ based on the single observation $X$. My attempt: $T=X^2$ is complete for $\theta$. 
The p.m.f for $T$ is
$$P(T=0)=1-2\theta,\ P(T=1)=2\theta$$
To show the completeness, I have the following:
$$E_{\theta}[g(T)]=0 \Leftrightarrow (1-2\theta)\cdot g(0)+2\theta\cdot g(1)=0$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ on both side:
$$-2g(0)+2g(1)=0$$
which implies that $g(0)=g(1)$, but I'm not sure how to do next to show $P_{\theta}(g(T)=0)=1$

Comment: Don't work with the derivative, work directly with $E_{\theta}$.   If you rearrange terms, you'll get $g(0) + 2\theta(g(1) - g(0)) = 0$.  For this to hold for all $\theta$... (you take over from here!)

Comment: Similar: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/496249/119261.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comment, $T(X) = X^2$ is complete if:

$$E_{\theta}[g(T(X))] = E_{\theta}[g(X^2)] = 0 \text{ for all } \theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \implies \\ g(T(X)) = g(X^2) = 0 \text{ with probability 1 for all } \theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] $$

As you've shown

$$E_{\theta}[g(X^2)] = 0 \text{ for all } \theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \implies g(0) + 2\theta (g(1) - g(0) ) = 0 \text{ for all } \theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$$
By plugging in some particular $\theta \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ show that the later implies that $g(0) = g(1) = 0$ and then use this to conclude your result.